# Batch file command with folder permissions

Tags: batch-file

I'm having a problem with this batch file command. I want a specific folder to have access to user and administrators but no one else. The command is denying everyone.

```
net use T: "\\sharedrive\Employee Documents\%USERNAME%"

md "\\sharedrive\Employee Documents\%USERNAME%" 

@IF Exist "\\sharedrive\Employee Documents\%USERNAME%" (

icacls "\\sharedrive\Employee Documents\%USERNAME%" /inheritance: rw

icacls "\\sharedrive\Employee Documents\%USERNAME%" /DENY Everyone: (CI) (OI) (F) 

ELSE IF icacls "\\sharedrive\Employee Documents\%USERNAME%" /GRANT "%USERNAME%: (CI) (OI) (F)

ELSE IF icacls "\\sharedrive\Employee Documents\%USERNAME%" /GRANT "Administrators: (CI) (OI) (F)

)
```